# Bad questions gaining fast (<5 min) upvotes

Tags: discussion, flags, sock-puppets

I just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071309/50k-messages-per-second-is-java-feasible), which struck me as yet another overly broad piece of garbage on the java tag, and much to my astonishment, it got 2 upvotes within about 2 minutes.

After re-reading the question to make sure I hadn't skipped a line, or missed it being posted by Jon Skeet, my mind screamed 'SOCKPUPPET/VOTING RING'.

The question has been put on hold as 'Unclear what you are asking', but it still got 2 upvotes really quickly, which is what disturbs me.

Now, this kind of profiling my not be helpful, but at what stage does this suspicion become valid and helpful to the moderation team?

Comment: If you suspect something, flag it for moderator attention. There could be any number of explanations; perhaps the OP has colleagues that are happy the OP asked the question on behalf of the team, but that don't realise they are forming a voting ring this way. We cannot see any indication of that, moderators can.

Comment: As an aside, if you find I've posted an overly broad piece of garbage, please still flag it for moderator attention and/or downvote it :)

Comment: Having dug through some searches in the past of "things with one upvote, no answers and closed" I find a lot of crap in there that somehow got upvotes.  I'd like to blame the first post review queue (I've seen this on other SE's) where the default action for many reviewers appears to be "upvote and say welcome".

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That account has been around for nearly three years and has only ever cast one vote. They'd received enough upvotes on earlier questions to earn the voting privilege, but they've only used it that one time. A couple of quick upvotes on a low-quality question is worth looking in to, but a cursory look at the user's profile eliminates sock puppetry rather quickly. Since that information is visible to everyone on the user's profile page, this isn't worth bringing to a moderator's attention, and it certainly wasn't worth bringing to Meta to single the user out for pile-on downvoting (-17 when I deleted the question out of pity).

Comment: Bad question, yes but -17 is a tiny bit harsh.

Comment: Harsh? This **is** StackOverflow. :-)

Comment: Harsh? This is the Meta-effect. :-)